# How would one take an object space normal map, and export a tangent space one?

Tags: normals, conversion

I have a model that comes with object space normal maps, and I need to get them exported as tangent normal maps in PNG format. I've tried Handplane, but it causes ugly seams in the map. So, I'm kind of stuck.

Any way to perform this conversion within blender? I'm a complete beginner to Blender, so I'll need a step-by-step.

Comment: Try looking here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/190634/75504 - Make sure to read the comments under the answer, because there are more detailed instructions, namely that to do _object space_ to _tangent space_ you need to do _object space_ to _world space_ first, then _world space_ to _tangent space_.