Convert height map to normal map in the shader editor
I can't find a way to convert greyscale image to normal map within the shader editor.
I don't talk about using height map to add details with bump/displacement node. I don't talk about baking details from an object to a normal map.
I talk about a node set up (I guess with math stuff) that convert the height/bump map from an image texture node to normal map colors with the 3 directional channel that I can use in the surface slot of my material output  node. To be clear, a real conversion as we can see on this sites :
https://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/
http://www.smart-page.net/smartnormal/
Based on what is already done in Blender I am 99% sure that it is feasible so I must admit that I am stunned to see that since so long ago no node set up to convert height map to normal map in shader editor has been made (or rather that I didn't find it) wich force us to go on external tools instead stay in Blender.

I guess the easiest way would be to simply use a Value to Normal node which is described here in the Blender 4.1 manual: Value to Normal node. Unfortunately despite being there in the documentation, the node does not exist in Blender.

@Gordon Brinkmann
This is not what I'm seeking for. I guess this node, if it existed (!) would convert a value in normal value in Blender, like the bump node currently do.

I know what you are seeking for, and well, the documentation says it computes height map to "normal map", whereas the description for the Bump node says it would generate "a perturbed normal from a height texture for bump mapping" . Strictly from the wording it sounds as if they did different things and actually I've found the node now - I thought it was in the Shader Editor, but it is in the Texture Node Editor. Something I never used and I have no idea how to produce an output from it... if I could I would at least check if it maybe is what you need.

@Gordon Brinkmann - I didn't see that node where in "texture editor" section. That why it confused me. I realize I didn't know that Blender have a texture editor. Your answer didn't help me for what I'm seeking but thank you for this discover! :)

Yeah sorry, if I knew I would have written a proper answer. And why exactly is baking not acceptable, because you want to use it "on the fly"?

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/190634/35559 . Is there a route from World Space Bump output ) > Object Space > Tangent Space Normals, using this?

@GordonBrinkmann I need to render it as a map in order to export it for real time work.

@RobinBetts on the site I gave as examples there is no question of space calculation, it's purely a conversion from an image to another.
